# Ajax Pagination on Ajax filter

Tags: wp-query, ajax, globals

Following this great tutorial I've implemented Ajax pagination with scrolling: https://www.billerickson.net/infinite-scroll-in-wordpress/.

Now, I've added a second Ajax call to filter the posts by category and I would to make pagination works also for the filtered posts.

So I thought to make something like this in function filter_posts() in functions.php:

```
function filter_posts() {
   global $wp_query;
   $args['category_name'] = $_POST['passed_slug_via_ajax'];

   query_posts($args);

    [loop]
    wp_send_json_success( $data );

   };
```

I thought that in this way, ie using `query_posts`, the current query `global $wp_query;` was altered to include the  `$args['category_name']` filter, so when I trigger the "more posts" function it would paginate the filtered results:

```
// more posts" function
function more_posts() {
  global $wp_query;
  $args['paged'] = $_POST['passed_page_via_ajax'];

  query_posts($args);

   [loop]
   wp_send_json_success( $data );

};
```

No way: the tiggered `more_posts()` function doesn't apply the filter...

So I've tried to manually alter the `global $wp_query;` in this way in `filter_posts()` function:

```
function filter_posts() {
   global $wp_query;
   $args['category_name'] = $_POST['passed_slug_via_ajax'];

   query_posts($args);

    [loop]
    $wp_query->set( "category_name", $_POST['passed_slug_via_ajax'] );
    wp_send_json_success( $data );

   };
```

But it doesn't work...

Maybe I didn't catch exactly the idea of how `global $wp_query;` it works?

Comment: to alter the query https://presscustomizr.com/snippet/three-techniques-to-alter-the-query-in-wordpress/

Comment: there is no global query object on an ajax request, you set all of the query arguments you need within your function and create a new query object, the same way the tutorial you linked does it.

Comment: @Milo There is: in the linked tutorial `wp_localize_script()` is used to pass to JS the global $wp_query object with `'query' => $wp_query->query`; then, function `be_ajax_load_more()` get all the $args it need from this global query object

Comment: @inarilo I knew that link but it explains nothing about my question

Comment: your tutorial is constructing a new wp_query object in the ajax functions, why are you using query_posts or global $wp_query? your code will work if you do it as in the tutorial

Comment: @AmintaCode that's on the page that the ajax request is made from. When the ajax call is made, it's a new request.

Comment: @Milo ok! So you can not do the opposite? Pass the modified value of  the `global $wp_query object` from function `be_ajax_load_more()` from functions.php to the page?

Comment: @AmintaCode There is no global query object, the query object is the one you create within your ajax function with `WP_Query`. The reason why a global query object exists on a front end request is because those parameters are derived automatically from the URL that was used to load that front end page. There is no such mechanism happening on an ajax request. There is no state maintained between separate requests.

Comment: @Milo thanks, now I've understood! And - accordingly - I've solved the problem via JS.

Answer (score 1):

As @Milo brilliantly pointed out, there is no such a thing like a global query object in Wordpress.

So I've solved the problem via JS, like this:

```
 var isFiltered = false;
 var filters;

 $(load_more_button).click(function(e) {
     load_more_handler(e);
 });

 $(filters_form).submit(function(e) {
     filter_handler(e);
 });

 function filter_handler(e) {
    isFiltered = true;

    filters = $(this).serialize();
    var data = {
        action: 'ajax_filter',
        query:  php_vars.query, // // query is got from wp_localize_script()
        filters: filters
    };
    $.post(php_vars.adminAjaxUrl, data, function(res) {
    [etc]

 };

 function load_more_handler(e) {

        var data = {
              action: 'ajax_load_more',
              query:    php_vars.query, // query is got from wp_localize_script()
              page: page,
              isFiltered: isFiltered,
              filters: filters
        };
        $.post(php_vars.adminAjaxUrl, data, function(res) {
        [etc]
 };
```

and in functions.php something like:

```
function ajax_load_more_posts() {

   $args = isset( $_POST['query'] ) ? array_map( 'esc_attr', $_POST['query'] ) : array();

     if( isset($_POST['isFiltered']) && ( $_POST['isFiltered'] ) ) {

         $filters = $_POST['filters'];
         $args = wp_parse_args(get_ajax_filters($filters), $args); // get_ajax_filters() is a custom utility function of mine to combine filters passed by Ajax and $args
        };

     [loop]
     wp_die();
 } ; 

add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_load_more', 'ajax_load_more_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_load_more', 'ajax_load_more_posts' );
```